# For loop with conditions in a function R

Tags: r, function, for-loop, conditional-statements

I would like to print something for every variable in a dataset. If the variable is a factor class, then I would like to print "variable x belongs in table 1", else "variable x belongs in table 2". For the table below, I should get:

"patientID belongs 2" 
"age belongs in table 2" 
"diabetes belongs in table 1" 
"status belongs in table 1"

```
patientID <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
age <- c(25, 34, 28, 52)
diabetes <- c("Type1", "Type2", "Type1", "Type1")
status <- c("Poor", "Improved", "Excellent", "Poor")
patientdata <- data.frame(patientID, age, diabetes, status)

patientdata$diabetes <- factor(patientdata$diabetes)
patientdata$status <- factor(patientdata$status)
```

My solution is incorrect, but it is what I have so far.

```
data_variables <- function(data_set){
  for(i in names(data_set)){
    if(class(i) == "factor"){
      var_details <- paste0(data_set$i, " belongs in table 1")
    }
    else{
      var_details <- paste0(data_set$i, " belongs in table 2")

    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `apply` [family](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/lapply) function to iterate over the data frame and check whether each column is a factor.

Then use [`ifelse`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/ifelse) to traverse the output and return the desired table name.

```r
ifelse(
    sapply(patientdata, is.factor), "table 2", "table 1"
)

# patientID       age  diabetes    status
# "table 1" "table 1" "table 2" "table 2"
```

In this case, you *could* also take advantage of the fact that the boolean output of `sapply` is stored as an integer which happens to be 1 less than the value of the number for the table you want to output, and so do something like:

```r
paste("table", sapply(patientdata, is.factor)+1)
# [1] "table 1" "table 1" "table 2" "table 2"
```

But I think this is a lot less readable and I wouldn't recommend it.